# Highlight one of the reference in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, highlighting

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[width=1.00cm, height=1.00cm, left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=1.00cm, bottom=1.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    I want to highlight the first reference \cite{casson1959flow} by yellow color in the reference section. How Can I make it possible? 
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{Bibliography.bib}
\end{document}
```

`.bib` file

```
@article{rosselandspringer,
  title={Springer-Verlag; Berlin: 1931},
  author={Rosseland, S},
  journal={Astrophysik und atom-theoretische Grundlagen.[Google Scholar]}
}



@book{liao2003beyond,
  title={Beyond perturbation: introduction to the homotopy analysis method},
  author={Liao, Shijun},
  year={2003},
  publisher={Chapman and Hall/CRC}
}


@article{yasir2023mathematical,
  title={Mathematical modelling of unsteady Oldroyd-B fluid flow due to stretchable cylindrical surface with energy transport},
  author={Yasir, Muhammad and Ahmed, Awais and Khan, Masood and Alzahrani, Abdullah Khamis and Malik, Zaka Ullah and Alshehri, Ahmed Mohammad},
  journal={Ain Shams Engineering Journal},
  volume={14},
  number={1},
  pages={101825},
  year={2023},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

Question: I want to highlight the first reference in the reference section.